# Highcharts xRange Chart timeline not shown when zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem trying to show a Xrange chart in my webapp.

Everything works ok until I try to zoom the chart and one of the extremes of the data entry falls outside the viewport, since then the graphic representation is not shown.

```
chart: {
        type: 'xrange',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts X-range study'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 1,
        opposite: false,
        categories: ["", ""],
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 0
        }
    }
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gyun8q3a/1/

Comment: x range is still under development. I believe that the best option is just reporting the bug on Highcharts github. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Thanks @morganfree, I will also make an issue ticket there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@morganfree* rightly said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221316/highcharts-xrange-chart-timeline-not-shown-when-zoom#comment69688793_41221316), at the time the OP asked the question x-range was still under development.

This bug was fixed in Highcharts version 6 but I was still experiencing the same issue in an Angular 5 application until I saw the comment from *oysteinmoseng* in the following bug report: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6577

**Be sure to include `modules/xrange.js` instead of the older `modules/xrange-series.js`.**